# Wikipedia API get image and info out of every page in list

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api

i have been trying to get all the data from this list https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Fungi_of_Canada . So that it would get the image and info from every mushroom as a JSON. But if i view the JSON it's really messy https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Amanita_frostiana&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json . Is there a easier way to fetch the data?

Answer (score 0):

Use prop=images instead:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Amanita_frostiana&prop=images

What do you mean by "info"?